# Google App Engine error during deploy response 2

Tags: google-app-engine

Using Node.js 8.14
it was working fine since I deployed a two days ago, but now suddenly error started to occur.
During deploy i get this error on remote console as :

The command is : `gcloud app deploy --project_name`

Error Log :

> Step #1: E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or
>   try with --fix-missing?
>
> Step #1: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE Step #1: npm ERR! errno 100
>
> Step #1: npm ERR! scraper@1.0.0 preinstall: `apt-get update && apt-get
>   -y install gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4
>   libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0
>   libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1
>   libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6
>   libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates
>   fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget`
>
> Step #1: npm ERR! Exit status 100 Step #1: npm ERR!  Step #1: npm ERR!
>   Failed at the scraper@1.0.0 preinstall script. Step #1: npm ERR! This
>   is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging
>   output above. Step #1: npm WARN Local package.json exists, but
>   node_modules missing, did you mean to install? Step #1:  Step #1: npm
>   ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: Step #1: npm ERR!
>   /root/.npm/_logs/2019-03-05T10_24_22_880Z-debug.log Step #1: error
>   building image: error building stage: waiting for process to exit:
>   exit status 1

more over, when I see the logs, it has lots of 404 error

> Step #1: E: Failed to fetch
>   http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/libpam-systemd_229-4ubuntu21.15_amd64.deb
>   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80] Step #1:  Step #1: E: Failed to
>   fetch
>   http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libg/libgd2/libgd3_2.1.1-4ubuntu0.16.04.10_amd64.deb
>   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80] Step #1:  Step #1: E: Failed to
>   fetch
>   http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nss/libnss3-nssdb_3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.4_all.deb
>   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80] Step #1:  Step #1: E: Failed to
>   fetch
>   http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nss/libnss3_3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.4_amd64.deb
>   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

Thanks in advance.